# Building ATLAS for NumPY/SciPy installation on Debian fails

Tags: linux, numpy, scipy, debian, atlas

I am following the instructions of this page to build ATLAS  : [SciPy Tutorial for building ATLAS](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html#building-atlas-by-hand)

when I want to configure ATLAS as it mentioned in the tutorial:

```
../configure -Fa alg -fPIC --with-netlib-lapack=/path/to/lapack/lapack_<XXXX>.a
```

It gives me this error message:

```
ERROR around arg 10 (--with-netlib-lapack=../../lapack-3.1.1/lapack_LINUX.a).
xconfig exited with 10
```

I am sure I am giving the correct path to lapack_LINUX.a.
What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried giving the absolute path to the LAPACK lib? [You can also point it at the LAPACK tar file](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node8.html). As an aside, I'd recommend [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) over ATLAS nowadays in terms of speed and ease of compilation.

Comment: I assume that you want to compile atlas to optimise it for your system. Under ubuntu, I was able to do this by using apt-get source atlas, which downloads the patched source package, which should be configured to compile painlessly on your system.

Comment: @ali_m As you suggested I switched to OpenBLAS and it works perfectly.